# How to load a font in pdflib?

Tags: php, fonts, pdflib

I'm trying to load an .otf font in Php 7.4.7 like this:

1. Add the resources path which according to the logs looks like it worked:

```
$pdflib = new pdflib();
$pdflib->set_option('textformat=utf8');
$pdflib->set_option('SearchPath={{fullpath/to/my/fonts}}');
```

the log show up to this point no errors:

```
[New category:resource "SearchPath:fullpath/to/my/fonts"]
```

2. But when loading the font like this:

```
$font = $pdflib->load_font("My-Font-Regular", "unicode", "embedding");
```

I get this error:

```
[Last exception 2516 in load_font]["Font 'My-Font-Regular' with encoding 'unicode': Font file (AFM, PFM, TTF, OTF etc.) or host font not found"]
```

I have tried utf-8 as encoding, giving full path when adding the search path and when loading the font, single and double curly braces when setting the search path but I could make more progress.

Also tried with no success:

```
$pdflib->set_option("stringformat=utf8");
```

I couldn't find any documentation for accepted encodings and the function it's not even described in the pdflib provided docs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in general this looks fine, but there are a few potential pitfalls when using the extension based search:

- the font file do not have one of the supported file extensions (like .ttf, .otf etc.)
- the font name you use is different to font file base name. In your case, `My-Font-Regular`. Do your font file have this name with the extension `.otf` => `My-Font-Regular.otf`
- the path `fullpath/to/my/fonts` (or a sub directory) has wrong read permissions for your PHP process.
- when working on Windows, please take care, that you apply a complete absolute path. (see PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 2.8 *PHP Binding* section *File name handling in PHP* for details.)

Please see PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 6.4.4 *Searching for Fonts* section *Extension-based search for font files* for a detailed explanation.

As you have already enabled logging, you can enable more details by adding **classes {filesearch=3}**. Please see PDFlib 9 API Reference, chapter 1.3 *Logging* for more details. This might give you more details. And I'm sure, [opening a Support case](https://www.pdflib.com/licensing-support/opening-a-support-case/) at PDFlib with sharing more details might also be an option.